# How to select drop-down and select checkbox inside table row-wise

Tags: java, selenium

i have already tried to loop and get row and column count but not sure how to select drop-down and click on checkbox after that.

i have already tried to loop and get row and column count but not sure how to select drop-down and click on checkbox after that.

Comment: Please post your code as a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: thanks Dmitriy! i was able to find solution to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some RND and found this solution. Basically I wrote a function for checkbox and it worked, posting my code here:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//*[@class='table table-striped ng-star-inserted']//tr") 
List<WebElement> Ques_Table_Rows;

@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//*[@class='table table-striped ng-star-inserted']//*[@ng-reflect-name='dataType']") 
List<WebElement> TypeDropdown;

for (int j = 0; j < Ques_Table_Rows;.size(); j++) 
{
    select_SelectMask(Mask.get(j));
}

void select_SelectMask(WebElement e) {
    e.click();
}
```

Similar way, I have written functions for other drop-downs, text-boxes as well.